# How to show dialog box when some one going to uninstall my application?

Tags: android

I face a problem.

Based on my requirement if any one will going to uninstall my application,

i mean after clicking Uninstall button ,i want to display a dialog box through 
my application.

Is it possible?.

If it possible please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is impossible due to the Android system application design.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

You cannot pause or stop the user from uninstalling your application for security reasons, as a malicious app could use that to prevent being uninstalled.

Comment: @kiran They launch their own dialog over the uninstall confirmation dialog by monitoring the logcat. Their method can easily be bypassed by uninstalling from the Play Store or using adb uninstall

Comment: hi me also used logcat output for getting uninstall event.but the log is generating differ form one mobile to another mobile.But AppLock is running in all mobiles how.thaks for u'r replay.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible , itseems ,as thatshow many anto virus applications prompts for user confirmation while uninstallation.